# Open Source Linux patch management

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, patch

I am looking for an open source patch management solution for the common Linux distributions. A product like Landscape, but free of charge. Before I start to build a solution with Ansible, Puppet or Chef, I prefer to ask here if someone has a suitable solution.

Requirements:

- Web interface with user management, host administration
- Update management (list of available updates, time-controlled and manual installation of all or individual updates, pin of updates)

Hopefully there will be a suitable solution, thank you for the answers.